# transcoding part anexB bitstream

Tags: go, ffmpeg, h.264, http-live-streaming, nalu

I'm using [gohlslib](https://github.com/bluenviron/gohlslib) for converting RTMP to HLS, this library gives me HLS and LHS with the transmuxing feature where each segment is of 2s.

But I also want to support the ABR, the flow with this is NALUs are packed in either AVCC or AnexB format and stored in fmp4 parts. []parts make one segment.

I was thinking if I could be able to transcode this anexB or AVCC stream format after its packed into fmp4.
I tried to check what's packed in parts and stored the output as .h264 file.

The first part of a segment has NALUs in this order  `SPS`  `PPS` `SPS` `PPS` `slice of IDR` `slice of non-IDR...`
but the later parts that are created don't have it.

Only the 1st part of every segment has `SPS`  `PPS` `SPS` `PPS` `slice of IDR`.

I may be wrong to say that this is what raw .h264 content.

My question is, is it even possible to transcode such part files using `Go` or `CXX` while maintaining same PTS and DTS of the transmuxed parts/segment